# What options are there for accessing volume shadow copy service snapshot files in a program?

Tags: c++, volume-shadow-service

I am creating a VSS snapshot in a program using C++ and the VSS API.  According to [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adioltean/2008/02/28/a-simple-way-to-access-shadow-copies-in-vista/) you can use the FindFirstFile/FindNextFile functions or create a symbolic link to the volume and go through the link to access the files in a VSS snapshot.  Are there any other ways?  Thanks.

Comment: Does the documentation mention other ways? This is off-topic, it's asking for general advice and there's no code for context.

Comment: Have you tried searching for open source projects that make use of VSS?

Comment: Thanks guys.  Tadman I was hoping to create a record of all possible options for enumerating through a VSS snapshot - do you consider that general advice?  No code necessary since this is not a coding question.  It seems appropriate to me...
Dgnuff I've pretty thoroughly googled it just wanted to get input from an expert.

Answer (score 0):

As the link itself says, `FindFirstFile` is just an example of how Win32 functions can access the VSS snapshot. You're incorrectly assuming it's somehow special. As the VSS snapshots are just filesystems, it would be exceptional for a file function to *not* work on them. Chances are high that even `std::ifstream` would work.

Comment: It does say they can't be viewed in explorer.  And when I try to access \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy35\ for VSS on my computer it fails.  If it's not transparent to the OS how are you supposed to access the snapshot?

Comment: @JoshOrenberg: Explorer would be shell-level; `FindFirstFile` is Win32 API level. Explorer isn't so much part of the OS as another program (it's explorer.EXE, after all).

Comment: I just tested with QDir set to the \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy##\ path and QDir.entryList() returned nothing so scratch that possibility. (using Qt framework)